# How to thoroughly delete the IBAction associated with a line in Xcode?

Tags: swift, ibaction

How can I thoroughly delete the `IBAction` associated with a blank line in `Xcode`? That line is in line 40, there’s no any association with my `UIButton` with line 40. I tried to press the delete key, then the black point disappeared, but after I click run the app the `Xcode` says failed to run, because that black point came back again.

So how can I thoroughly delete the `IBAction` associated with a blank line? Thank you!

Comment: You are referencing a line number but there is no code...

Comment: Can you show your code, or at least a screenshot to show the error?

Comment: @Miladinho So how can I redo the referencing? Because I intend to do nothing with that line

Comment: Sunshine I was basically saying what @emprepun is asking you, please show your code or be more clean about what it is you want. But from what it sounds like, just delete "@IBAction" part from the line an that's it, unless you dragged and dropped an IBAction from the storyboard or a Xib file into your code, then you must go to that component you dragged from and remove the reference, look at the answer you got below on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the button, go into storyboard. Then go to the panel (where you set the properties) and click the one with the arrow. Press the x next to your button.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edfgo.png)